# How to configure lock wait time

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my web application, I use Spring 4.2.9.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.8.Final,  Spring Data 1.8.2.RELEASE, and MS SQLSERVER 2014 Enterprise.

I would like to configure the lock wait time instead of using the default one (-1, which means wait forever). Based on my research, I need to define a value for

```
javax.persistence.lock.timeout
```

However, I am not able to find an example of how to define it. Here is my configuration:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="derek6HikariCP" />
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="${jdbc.connectionTestQuery}" />
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="${jdbc.dataSourceClassName}" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maximumPoolSize}" />
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="${jdbc.minimumIdle}" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="${jdbc.idleTimeout}" />
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${jdbc.connectionTimeout}" />
        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
                <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
                <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>     
    </bean>

    <bean  id="entityManagerFactory" name="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="myproject.domain" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${hibernate.max_fetch_depth}</prop>                                 
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>     

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>   

    <context:annotation-config />  

    <jpa:repositories base-package="myproject.repository"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a property under `jpaProperties` to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`?

Comment: I haven't tried it because I am not sure whether that is the place to put it. I googled a lot, and I am unable to find a single example for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only solution to this, but you don't need to define it in your configuration. Albeit not the perfect solution, you can directly pass this as a property to your `EntityManager` queries. For example:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 0L);

EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
try {
    entityManager.find(Entity.class, id, LockModeType, properties); 
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();                        
} finally {
    entityManager.close();
}
```

You can find more documentation on this here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html